# ion-datetime-button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic

Como puedo hacer para cambiarle el formato en el que se muestra la fecha del datetime-button?

```
<ion-datetime-button datetime="datetime" displayFormat="DD/MMM/YYYY"></ion-datetime-button>
```

Comment: En la documentación te muestra los formatos [Ionic API Input for Datetime Format Picker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime#iso-8601-datetime-format-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmz)